# Change all aria-expanded on a page to false with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some FAQs on a page that I need to open up before parsing the HTML because the text value of the answer is hidden and therefore coming up empty when  parsing the HTML of the page.

When I use the code below in the browser it returns me all the links but it doesn't change the "aria-expanded" attribute to "false".

```
 $('a').each(function() { this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false')});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try with *.attr()* (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')}

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way should work:

```
$(function () {
     $('a').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
     });
});
```

Comment: Here is what i get back after running your code: $(function () { $('a').each(function() {$(this).attr('aria-expanded', 'false')});});
Object { context: HTMLDocument → newsite, length: 1, 1 more… }
‘mozHidden’ and ‘mozVisibilityState’ are deprecated.  Please use the unprefixed ‘hidden’ and ‘visibilityState’ instead.

Comment: @kellykels21 could you update your poste with your browser name & version and jquery version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `this` refers to the objects (a tags) you want. You might try the following code.

```
$('a').each(function(index, obj) { $(obj).attr('aria-expanded', 'false') });
```

Answer (score 0):

setAttribute is native JavaScript function. Use attr() of jquery.

$('a').each(function() { this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')});

Comment: For some reason Firefox says that this.attr() is not a function??

Comment: this is not defined at the current scope.
 each function callback takes arguments as index and the current element.

try using:

 $('a').each(function(index, element) { $(element).attr('aria-expanded', 'false') });